# Symfony 2 cannot generate new bunlde

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, bundle

I just joined ServerGrove and got a VPS. I installed Symfony 2 and unpacked it in my www folder. I ran this command `php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Pixbelly/HomeBundle --format=yml` but I receive this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.
```

I ran this command from www/Symfony and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: run `php app/console` without any arguments to see the list of available commands and usage. Also, did you install the vendors?

Comment: I see Doctrine:generate, but nothing to generate a namespace. I guess I have to add it?

Comment: Turns out this worked php app/console init:bundle Pixbelly/HomeBundle src

Answer (score 2):

check if you have installed and activated SensioGeneratorBundle.

in app/AppKernel.php

```
    $bundles = array(
        new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle(),
        ...
```

like in http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html

maybe also check your composer.json:

```
    "require": {
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*", // here maybe newer version
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*", // same thing
        ...
```

then clear your cache and do

```
    composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

please see this video, the correct syntax to generate bundle command (I am using ubuntu 13.04 Os) is:

```
./app/console generate:bundle
```

http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-getting-easier-interactive-generators

I hope above video link is useful to you

sorry for replying on this old thread, today I come across the same problem and found this link, thought may be I should mention it here, could be useful to somebody in future

Comment: why down vote for this answer? what's wrong or misleading in it?